# Remove elements from numpy array?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

i have a numpy array as

```
text = [[...],[...],[...],[...]]
```

number of elements in text is 4 X 80.

```
Values = [[...],[...],[...],[...]]
```

Number of elements in values is 4 X 80

Now What I want to do is remove all the spaces at the last after the string characters ends in the `text` text[3] block and I want to remove the corresponding index in values as well,

How to attain this in fastest way?

I want it to generalised so when elements increase , it should work.

Updating code while learning from net

** Now how to delete those 30 elements from last**

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[...],[...],[...],[...]])
count = 0
for elem in reversed(a[len(a)-1]):
    if elem == ' ':
        count = count + 1
        #new = np.delete(a[len(a)-1], np.where(elem == ' '), axis=0)
    if elem != ' ':
        break
```

Comment: what do you mean by `after string character ends?`

Comment: In the text[3] the last elemts are appended with spaces only which needs to be removed

Comment: what do you mean by removing corresponding index? can 0 or ' ' be put there. otherwise shape will no longer remain same.

Comment: Right now the shapes are same so when last appending spaces will be removed as well as their corresponding index in values the shape will be same na

Comment: Oh yeah I got you , ya shape doesn't matter text[3] can have lesser elements then the rest of text shapes

Comment: if we are just to update `text` 3, you count the last values that are `"  "` ie 30 and delete them. or simply pop them out until you get to a character. then stop. Count how many you popped out and delete the same number from the calues

Comment: I should count from reverse , Ya that will be great, So numpy.delete will work?

Comment: What had your tried? Can you show your code?

Comment: @FrankAK Currently I am trying to delete elements from multidimensional numpy array but Can't get it :) I am kinda new to numpy

Comment: @FrankAK Can you help in deletion of elements from multidimensional numpy array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function that only pops out the last spaces:

```
 def mm(a,b):
       v = a.pop()
       if v==" ":
           b.pop()
           mm(a,b)
       else: a.append(v)
```

Now run the code on your lists / It will be good to run on a small data to ensure it runs before you run this on your whole data as it modifies the original data/ calling by reference.

```
[mm(x,y) for x,y in zip(text,Values)]
```

Now what is the size of the remaining list?

```
[len(x) for x in Values]
[80, 80, 80, 50]

[len(x) for x in text]
[80, 80, 80, 50]
```

The code only impacted the third list element

Answer (score 1):

At the first step, use `where` get what you want.

```
In [20]: np.where(a !=' ')
Out[20]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
        3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
        3, 3, 3, 3]),
 array([ 1,  3,  4,  6,  7,  8,  9, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 23, 24,
        26, 27, 28, 29, 31, 33, 34, 36, 37, 38, 39, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47, 48,
        49, 51, 53, 54, 56, 57, 58, 59, 61, 63, 64, 66, 67, 68, 69, 71, 73,
        74, 76, 77, 78, 79,  1,  3,  4,  6,  7,  8,  9, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17,
        18, 19, 21, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, 31, 33, 34, 36, 37, 38, 39, 41,
        43, 44, 46, 47, 48, 49, 51, 53, 54, 56, 57, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64,
        65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 71, 73, 74, 76, 77, 79,  1,  3,  5,  6,  7,  8,
        10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 19, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
        31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 40, 42, 43, 45, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54,
        55, 56, 57, 59, 60, 61, 62, 64, 65, 66, 68, 70, 71, 73, 74, 75, 76,
        77, 78, 79,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  9, 11, 12, 14, 15, 17,
        19, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 33, 34, 35, 37, 39, 40, 42,
        43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]))
```

And then filter it by:

```
In [21]: a[np.where(a !=' ')]
Out[21]: 
array(['I', 'a', 'm', 'g', 'o', 'o', 'd', 'I', 'a', 'm', 'g', 'o', 'o',
       'd', 'I', 'a', 'm', 'g', 'o', 'o', 'd', 'I', 'a', 'm', 'g', 'o',
       'o', 'd', 'I', 'a', 'm', 'g', 'o', 'o', 'd', 'I', 'a', 'm', 'g',
       'o', 'o', 'd', 'I', 'a', 'm', 'g', 'o', 'o', 'd', 'I', 'a', 'm',
       'g', 'o', 'o', 'd', 'I', 'a', 'm', 'g', 'o', 'o', 'd', 'I', 'a',
       'm', 'g', 'o', 'o', 'd', 'I', 'a', 'm', 'g', 'o', 'o', 'd', 'I',
       'a', 'm', 'g', 'o', 'o', 'd', 'I', 'a', 'm', 'g', 'o', 'o', 'd',
       'I', 'a', 'm', 'g', 'o', 'o', 'd', 'n', 'e', 'w', '_', 'i', 't',
       'e', 'm', 's', '=', '[', 'x', 'i', 'f', 'x', '%', '2', 'e', 'l',
       's', 'e', 'N', 'o', 'n', 'e', 'f', 'o', 'r', 'x', 'i', 'n', 'i',
       't', 'e', 'm', 's', ']', 'n', 'e', 'w', '_', 'i', 't', 'e', 'm',
       's', '=', '[', 'x', 'i', 'f', 'x', '%', '2', 'e', 'l', 's', 'e',
       'N', 'o', 'n', 'e', 'f', 'o', 'r', 'x', 'i', 'n', 'i', 't', 'e',
       'm', 's', ']', 'n', 'e', 'w', '_', 'i', 't', 'e', 'm', 's', '=',
       '[', 'x', 'i', 'f', 'x', '%', '2', 'e', 'l', 's', 'e', 'N', 'o',
       'n', 'e', 'f', 'o', 'r', 'x', 'i', 'n', 'i', 't', 'e', 'm', 's',
       ']', '\\', 'n'],
      dtype='|S1')
```

Comment: I don't want to remove all white spaces but the whiite spaces from back till a char is found of the numpy list in a multidimensional array